# javascript: use of greaterthan with strings

Tags: javascript

I am confused in understanding this
"9">"099" returns true and "9">"99" returns false(9 is just an example, it is happening like "x">"xabc" returns false and "x">"abc" returns true, where a is smaller than x but abc is greater tha x and a,b,c,x are numbers). Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"x" > "xabc"` returns false and `"x" > "abc"` returns true

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> it is happening like "x">"xabc" returns true and "x">"abc" returns false, where a is smaller than x but abc is greater tha x and a,b,c,x are numbers)

Yes (except that `"abc"` is *not* greater than `"x"`, and those are characters, not numbers). It's a *textual* comparison, the numbers in the strings are not converted to numbers before comparing them. So the comparison works character by character, stopping the first time it finds a difference. In your `"99" > "099"` case, since the `"9"` in the left-hand string is greater than the `"0"` in the right-hand string, the result is determined by just the first character. (The same thing happens in `"x" > "abc"`, because the `"x"` is greater than the `"a"`.)

Note that there's a very big difference between:

```
console.log("99" > "099"); // "true"
```

and

```
console.log(99 > "099"); // "false"
```

In the latter case, because one of the operands is a number, the JavaScript engine will try to convert the *other* operand into a number and then compare the numbers. In the former case, because *both* operands are strings, it won't, it'll do a textual comparison.

Side note: Be careful of numeric strings starting with `0` (like "099"). If they end up being implicitly converted to a number, they *may* get treated as octal (base 8) depending on the JavaScript engine being used.

Answer (score 3):

`x>abc`  is returns true because `x` has `ascii` value more than `a`

but `x>xbc` is false though `x` has `ascii` value equal to `x`, but for the second character in both the string, the first string `x` has only one character, while the second string `xbc` has `b` as second character..

in `x>abc`

`x` is compared with `a`, when in first character position `x` is greater than `a`, hence it returns `true`

in second example `x>xbc`, first `x` is compared with `x`, which returns `0`, since both have same ascii value..

but then `b` is compared with `""` since `"x"` has only `"x"` while `"xbc"` has `"b"` as second charatcer.. being in existence hence `xb` is greater than `x`

so it returns `false`

Comment: *"x>abc is returns false because x has ascii value more than a"* Two things: 1. It's `true`, not `false`. 2. JavaScript uses Unicode (er, mostly), not ASCII.