# Check Previous and Current Value in Variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

First, Check my codes:

```
<button id="submit">Roll</button>

<script>
    
function randomNumber(length) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = '123456789';
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}


var oldNumber = 0;

$('#submit').click(function(){
    
    var winner = false;
    
    var currentNumber = randomNumber(3);
    
    if(currentNumber > oldNumber){
        winner = true;
    }
    
    oldNumber = currentNumber;
    
    alert(winner);
})

</script>
```

Now problem is that all rounds winner is true, `oldNumber` just have 0 value.
In fact, I want to check the large and small number of rounds.

Comment: I don't think there is a mistake in your code. When I press 'roll` a couple of times it results in both `false` and `true`.

Comment: I think this code is work on browser, when i use this code on nodejs, the oldNumber just have 0 value.

Comment: I get `true` and `false` too. But what bothers me is that your `randomNumber` function returns a String, not a Number. This may screw up your comparison. For example, `"2" > "42"` will return `true`. Instead of `return result;`, do `return parseInt(result, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

Your code probably restarts every time you run it using `nodejs`. Try initially setting `oldNumber` to a random number.

```js
<button id="submit">Roll</button>

<script>
    
function randomNumber(length) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = '123456789';
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}


var oldNumber = randomNumber(3);

$('#submit').click(function(){
    
    var winner = false;
    
    var currentNumber = randomNumber(3);
    
    if(currentNumber > oldNumber){
        winner = true;
    }
    
    oldNumber = currentNumber;
    
    alert(winner);
})

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks,
When i insert oldNumber before exporting module, then this will worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your `randomNumber()` function always returns numeric string and you assigned this string type number to `currentNumber` variable. After that you compare the `currentNumber` (actually a string) with `oldNumber` (which is actually a number). I think problem lies in there and also the `randomNumber()` implementation. You should compare two number type values not two different types number values.

```
 if(currentNumber > oldNumber){
      winner = true;
 }
```

In above code, when you compare a numeric string (currentNumber) and actual number (oldNumber), JS does a textual comparison on both operands. `randomNumber()` never returns a numeric string that starts with "0" and you always gets a numeric string that greater than "0". e.g. `currentNumber="123"` and `oldNumber=0`, when comparing these two,  JS does textual comparison and converts other operand (`oldNumber`) from a number `0` to a numeric string `'0'`. As `'1'` comes later in comparsion with `'0'`. You will get always true. For more info do a visit this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001829/javascript-use-of-greaterthan-with-strings). Try to fix `randomNumber()` implementation and make sure it always return number type value not numeric string.